# Каким образом тестировать функции сервера

Tags: golang

Всем привет

Немного не понимаю, как тестировать сервер. В источниках о тестировании в качестве входного параметра применяется `*tesing.T` , а что если мне нужно протестировать функцию которая имеет в качестве входного параметра `w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request`?

Например как быть если я хочу протестировать функцию

```
func GetAllUserDataForReg(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) []byte {
    r.ParseForm()
    data := &myjson.JSONRequest{}
    data.Password, _ = bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(r.FormValue("password")), 12)
    data.Username = r.FormValue("username")
    data.Email = r.FormValue("email")
    data.Token = shortuuid.New()
    data.Useragent = r.Header.Get("User-Agent")
    data.Host, _, _ = net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
    data.ExistsUser, _, _ = dbclient.ExistsUser(data.Username)
    data.PasswordEmpty = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(data.Password, []byte("")) == nil
    marsh, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
    }

    return marsh
}
```

Как будет выглядеть тест такой функции?

Comment: если не забуду. то завтра напишу

Answer (score 2):

создайте файл, имя которого заканчивается `_test`, чтобы гошный тестовый фреймворк понял, что это тестовый файл.
имя теста должна начинаться с `Test_`, аргумент должен быть либо `*testing.T`, либо `*testing.TB`

Язык из коробки предотсавляет пакеты для тестирования, например "net/http/httptest"

```
func Test_GetAllUserDataForReg(t *testing.T) {
    reqURL := "/my/url"
    reqBody := "testdata"
    wantHTTPStatus := 200
    wantPayload := `testdata`

    resp := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, reqURL, strings.NewReader(reqBody))
    require.NoError(t, err)

    retData := GetAllUserDataForReg(resp, req)

    require.Equal(t, wantHTTPStatus, resp.Code)
    require.Equal(t, wantPayload, string(retData))
    require.Equal(t, wantPayload, resp.Body.String())
}

func GetAllUserDataForReg(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) []byte {
    bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    // обычно нужно отвечать чрез ResponseWriter. 
    // просто добавил ради примера  
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(bodyBytes))
    return bodyBytes
}
```